# PO Line Account selector selection doesn't display in field

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization that overrides the Purchase Order Line Account field drop-down lookup selector on the Purchase Order screen. It populates like I want, but the account selected from the dropdown doesn't display in the grid field after chosen. Here it is:

```
[PXSelector(
    typeof(Search5<Account.accountID,
        InnerJoin<PMCostBudget, On<Account.accountGroupID, Equal<PMCostBudget.accountGroupID>>>,
        Where2<Where<PMCostBudget.projectID, Equal<Current<POLine.projectID>>, Or<Current<POLine.projectID>, IsNull>>,
            And2<Where<PMCostBudget.projectTaskID, Equal<Current<POLine.taskID>>, Or<Current<POLine.taskID>, IsNull>>,
            And2<Where<PMCostBudget.costCodeID, Equal<Current<POLine.costCodeID>>, Or<Current<POLine.costCodeID>, IsNull>>,
            And<Where<Current<POLine.lineType>, Equal<POLineType.nonStock>, Or<Current<POLine.lineType>, IsNull>>>>>>,
        Aggregate<GroupBy<Account.accountID>>,
        OrderBy<Asc<Account.accountCD>>>),
        DescriptionField = typeof(Account.description),
        Filterable = false, 
        SelectorMode = PXSelectorMode.DisplayModeValue
        )]
```

It basically filters on the line type, project, task, and cost code selected on the same PO line.  What am I missing or doing wrong so that the selected AccountCD value will display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acumatica support's suggestion solved my problem. Since the Account id is a segmented key, I needed to manually change the PXSegmentedValue to a PXSelector in the .ASPX to get it to work. I also got it to work without that change by using a PXDimensionSelector instead of a plain PXSelector in the override.

```
    [PXDimensionSelector(AccountAttribute.DimensionName,
        typeof(Search5<Account.accountID>...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rest of your customization properly handled the override and the selector itself works (I think that is what you are saying)... If you need to display AccountCD, you should add SubstituteKey = typeof(Account.accountCD).  Without that, the selector is set right now to display the AccountID.

```
[PXSelector(
    typeof(Search5<Account.accountID,
        InnerJoin<PMCostBudget, On<Account.accountGroupID, Equal<PMCostBudget.accountGroupID>>>,
        Where2<Where<PMCostBudget.projectID, Equal<Current<POLine.projectID>>, Or<Current<POLine.projectID>, IsNull>>,
            And2<Where<PMCostBudget.projectTaskID, Equal<Current<POLine.taskID>>, Or<Current<POLine.taskID>, IsNull>>,
            And2<Where<PMCostBudget.costCodeID, Equal<Current<POLine.costCodeID>>, Or<Current<POLine.costCodeID>, IsNull>>,
            And<Where<Current<POLine.lineType>, Equal<POLineType.nonStock>, Or<Current<POLine.lineType>, IsNull>>>>>>,
        Aggregate<GroupBy<Account.accountID>>,
        OrderBy<Asc<Account.accountCD>>>),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(Account.accountCD),
        DescriptionField = typeof(Account.description),
        Filterable = false, 
        SelectorMode = PXSelectorMode.DisplayModeValue
        )]
```

On PXSelector, the first "typeof" is the value to be selected.  You can add subsequent typeof() references if you want to designate fields to display in the PXSelector (if your intent is to display an actual selector).

SubstituteKey = typeof(DAC Field) alters the selector's display to show the designated field rather than the actual value.  It is very common to select the recordID field and substitute the recordCD field.

DescriptionField displays the field designated after the displayed valued (the specifically selected field or the SubstituteKey field if specified).  I could be wrong, but I don't believe this shows when the selector is displayed in a grid.  I believe it only applies to form fields, such as if you toggle the grid row to a form view.

Filterable is optional, but it allows you to set filters in the selector, such as when you have a lot of records to retrieve and may want to quickly locate a value.  I believe there is some overhead to using it, so setting to false as you did could be a tiny performance gain.

I never used SelectorMode before, so you taught me something new here!  If adding SubstituteKey does not resolve your issue, you might try removing the SelectorMode line to see if that resolves your issue.  By the way it reads, that could be changing the behavior of the selector from what I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I should have mentioned that I already tried using the SubstituteKey you mention, and I added SelectorMode only while trying misc. things to get it to work.  Just to be sure, I did as you suggest for verification, and it still does not work.  The selector itself works as I would expect and displays data based on the PO line data entered, but the selected AccountCD value does not display after selection.